# Device policy manager camera blocked callback

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I have disabled camera using

```
    devicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(devicePolicyAdmin, true);
```

But I want to get a callback whenever user access camera and it is blocked by device policy manager.

Is there any broadcast or event for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no callback for that unfortunately

You will have to regularly check events from `UsageEvents` class and see if Camera is called to foreground